# Is it normal for kitten to stray off for a week?

Tags: cats, behavior, safety, lost-pet

We had three stray kitten of which one have gone missing. We were used to feeding them since their mother had left them (actually we have not seen her since, which is unusual, and wonder if something happened to her) and two of these had went off exploring the neighbourhood together. However, only one returned, that too, after two days and we waited hoping the other will come back too. Now it has been almost a week and still no sign of him/her.

Is this normal for kitten to do usually? I mean it's okay for me if it has found some other place to live and decides not to come back, but I am just worried whether it is in some danger.

Comment: Any cat that lives outside is in danger. If the kitten hasn't returned to a known source of food, then there are only two possibilities. Either the kitten is now confined (captured by a rescue or taken inside a house), or deceased.

Comment: Oh.. Exactly the thing that I was worrying about..

Comment: @AllisonC Not necessarily. He might still be wandering around another source of food. Another family might be caring about him in their garden and he might decide to venture back to the original owner.